# adding a view to UISplitViewController in Storyboard, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

in my application i have a UISplitView, but before this gets loaded I need to display a page where the user enters some details and then clicks okay to display the spitView. I have tried dragging a view controller from the object library on the right but this gives problems. Please advise me on the right way to approach what I'm trying to do,

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would have the splitview present the viewController that collects the user data. Present it modally then dismiss it after they enter the data and the split view will be there for you.